# References for heights of algebraic or projective variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, heights, diophantine-geometry

In my research I am using the notion of a $\textbf{rational function f on a domain}\: U\subset \mathbb C^{n}$. By this I mean that the graph of $f$ is an analytic component of an affine variety $X$ definable over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. (Analytic component - closure of a connected component of $X\backslash sing(X)$).

Such a function has a notion of $\textbf{complexity}$ - the minimal degree of such $X$ (By degree of affine variety I mean the degree of its projective closure, note that I am working with a coordinate system). I wish to define a notion of $\textbf{height}$ for $f$, which is the minimal height of such $X$.

My question - Is there any nice reference for heights of algebraic varieties (Not heights on algebraic varieties!), where I can find basic definitions and proofs for basic properties.

More specifically, I want to bound the height of the intersection, union, and projection of two projective varieties of given height. This will allow me to bound the height of the sum and product of two algebraic functions of given height, which is my ultimate goal.

Thank you!